# How to read a premade database into SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite, jdbc

I'm trying to open two databases I've been given, university and lsh. Whenever I try `.read university` or `.read lsh` I get the correct information but it's unreadable. It seems to have a load of ASCII characters inserted between each entry, but the correct data is definitely in there.

Here's an image of what I'm seeing:

[image: produced by .read university]

Comment: What is in those files? And why the tag "jdbc"?

Comment: @CL. There is a premade database that has breaches of referential integrity inside which I need to identify using JDBC and make a report on.

Comment: And what is inside those files?

Comment: @CL. "lsh" and "university" are both the databases themselves (because I am using SQLite) edit: they also have no extension

Comment: @CL. SQL or SQLite, I thought they were interchangeable?

Comment: `.read` expects a text file with SQL commands; this is not the same as the database file itself.

Comment: @CL. I have a file like that, I've tried the same thing `.read list_lsh.sqll` (sqll is what my proff called sqllite files) but it gives an error like this: `Error: near line X: no such table: tablename`

Comment: I guess you are supposed to edit the file, or to use it with an existing database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To connect an existing database in so that you can manipulate it as well as the main database (there's always a main database; you either named it when you started the DB connection/shell, or it is a temporary in-memory database) you use [`ATTACH DATABASE`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html)

```
ATTACH DATABASE 'university' AS university
```

Then, you can access the tables, views, indices, etc. of the attached database like this:

```
SELECT name,building FROM university.departments
```

Answer (score 0):

To open a database file, you have to run the `sqlite3` with the file name as parameter:

```
$ sqlite3 university                        <-- this is how you start it
SQLite version 3.8.3.1 2014-02-11 14:52:19
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite>
```